# Why is my local git settings not overriding the global in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, git-config

I have a git server set up with a self signed certificate. I have the following git config:

```
$ git config --local --get http.sslVerify
false

$ git config --global --get http.sslverify
true

$ git --version
git version 2.6.2.windows.1
```

When I'm pushing from git bash it works as expected and don't complain about the self signed certificate but when I push from Visual Studio 2015 it complains about the self signed certificate:

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception:
    The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

    Inner Exception:
        The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

When looking at the git settings from within Visual Studio git settings it looks as expected:

[image: Visual Studio git settings]

What do I need to do to be able to push from within Visual Studio.

I'm running Visual Studio Professional 2015 (Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2)

EDIT: I stage and commit from within Visual Studio and that works (as in it has picked up my name and email). It has also picked up some global other global settings like `core.editor` and `credential.helper`.

Comment: Are you sure, Visual Studio uses `git push`? I had such an issue with Matlab where Bash was fine but Matlab knew nothing (in my case about the credentials).

Comment: I believe so. In Visual Studio under Team Explorer I click the little house and get to the Team Explorer Home screen. From there I click Sync and under the header Outgoing Commits I have my pending commits and a hyperlink that says Push (along with the other git sync commands fetch and pull).

Comment: In my case the solution was to use ssh-key instead creadential helper. Perhaps you have to contact them.